# addEventListener и removeEventListener

Tags: javascript

На сайте, в шапке две кнопки, допустим 1 и 2. При нажатии кнопки 2 на странице начинается цикличное обновление, вот код:

```html
// Получим наш элемент
  var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[1];

  // Событие, которое происходит при клике на элемент
  li.addEventListener('click', function once(){
      setInterval(function once(){
    li.click();
  }, 5000);
  });
```

Требуется при нажатии на кнопку 1 остановить обновление, а если снова нажата клавиша 2 его продолжить и по кругу.

Пробовал стопить вот так:

```html
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
// Событие, которое происходит при клике на параграф

function once() {
    li.removeEventListener("click", once);
  }
  li.addEventListener("click", once);
```

Не работает, помогите все сделать правильно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элементы

```
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[1];
```

и

```
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
```

разные элементы.

---

```js
var li_0 = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
var li_1 = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[1];
var timer;
var counter = 0;

li_1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (!timer) {
    console.log("starting");
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      // some useful code
      console.clear();
      console.log(++counter);
    }, 1000);
  }
});

li_0.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log("stopping");
  timer = clearInterval(timer);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Click to Stop</li>
  <li>Click to Start</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Да действительно, они разные, каждый к своей кнопке, к сожалению код не работает (

Comment: @Влад Код работает. Вы неаккуратно скопировали его к себе.

Comment: Попробовал еще раз, все равно не работает.

Comment: @Влад Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" в ответе.

Comment: Я вижу это и тут и в хроме, в логе события идут, но данные не обновляются, то есть по таймеру "click" по li_1 не происходит.

Comment: @Влад "click" по li_1 запускает таймер. Зачем Вам его вызывать в событии таймера?

Comment: Я не понимаю вопроса)) Вот этот код работает 
  var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[1];

  // Событие, которое происходит при клике на элемент
  li.addEventListener('click', function once(){
      setInterval(function once(){
    li.click();
  }, 5000);
  });

Comment: Как только его потом отключить при клике на var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0]; не понятно

Comment: @Влад Да, Вы не понимаете, что Вы делаете. Прочитайте мой комментарий еще раз. Не торопитесь. Подумайте.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var li_0 = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
var li_1 = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[1];
var timer;

li_1.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if (!timer) {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        li_1.click();
    }, 5000);
  }
});

li_0.addEventListener('click', function() {
  timer = clearInterval(timer);
});
```

Вот так выглядит решение сего вопроса, благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Решение? Это код из моего ответа! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: На авторство не претендую)) Но, то что в коде не было команды click(); подозрительно))

Comment: Ваше решение мне очень помогло, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В продолжении темы собрал еще один скрипт:

```html
var li_1 = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[1];
var li_2 = document.getElementsByClassName('btn grey order')[3];
var timer;

li_1.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if (!timer) {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        li_1.click();
    }, 10000);
  }
});

li_2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  timer = clearInterval(timer);
});
```

который запускает таймер по клику на одну кнопку li_1 и должен остановить его на li_2, но остановка не происходит. Что не так и что ему надо?